# How to push public docker images to an artifactory using Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory, jfrog-container-registry

I am trying to push a public image (confluentic/cp-zookeeper) under a different name into jfrog artifactory using Jenkins, with a Jenkinsfile. I have tried in pulling the image and retagging it but it doesn't work. I currently have one step to push my own dockerfile to the artifact, so I know the pipeline works.
any help would be appreciate it

Comment: Why exactly didn't retagging work? Could you provide the error message?

Comment: Add the stage and console output of the error you're facing.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to define a stage like...

```
  stage {
    steps {
      script {
        docker.withRegistry(registry, credentials) 
        {
          def dockerImage = docker.build("acme-dockerv2-virtual.jfrog.io/hello-world")

          dockerImage.push()
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Where this assume registry is something like `acme-dockerv2-virtual.jfrog.io`, and credentials are whatever you need for artifactory...